# Basic PHP PostgreSQL Query

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

This is my first time working with PHP. I'm trying to take input from a form, make a Postgres query query based on that input, and then print out the results to the webpage.

**My index.html looks like this:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="table.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <select name="theMonth"> 
                <option value="01">January</option>
                <option value="02">February</option>
                <!--(more month options excluded)-->
            </select>
            <select name="theDay">
                <option value="01">01</option>    
                <option value="02">02</option>
                <!--(More day options excluded)-->
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**My table.php looks like this:**

```
  1 <?php
  2 $conn= pg_connect("host=mySchool dbname= myDBNAME user=me password=myPassword");
  3 if (!$conn) {
  4   print "An error occurred.\n";
  5   exit;
  6 }
  7 
  8 $result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM olympics WHERE EXTRACT(month from "closing_ceremony_date")=theMonth AND EXTRACT(day from "closing_ceremony_date") = theYear");
  9 if (!$result) {
 10   print "An error occurred.\n";
 11   exit;
 12 }
 13 
 14 while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
 15   print "Athlete: $row[0] Year: $row[3]";
 16   print "<br />\n";
 17 }
 18 
 19 ?>
```

Currently, submitting the form gives me a generic **Internal Sever Error** and I'm not sure how to debug from here. I don't have access to the logs, as it's hosted on a school server and I don't have the permissions to access them.

Any input/pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Your form fields are `name="theMonth"`|`name="theDay"` which you would access as `$_POST['theMonth']`|`$_POST['theDay']` not just `theMonth`|`theYear` (also, your field `theDay`!=`theYear`. Also, your double quotes are possibly causing the syntax error, try -> `"SELECT * FROM olympics WHERE EXTRACT(month from closing_ceremony_date)={$_POST['theMonth']} AND EXTRACT(day from closing_ceremony_date) = {$_POST['theYear']}"` (assuming you have a form field named `name="theYear"` and not just Month/Day

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to use the "$" signs on your sql or to escape the double quotes:

so the line 8 will be:

```
$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM olympics WHERE EXTRACT(month from $closing_ceremony_date)=theMonth AND EXTRACT(day from $closing_ceremony_date) = theYear");
```

or

```
$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM olympics WHERE EXTRACT(month from \"closing_ceremony_date\")=theMonth AND EXTRACT(day from \"closing_ceremony_date\") = theYear");
```

and you forgot to use the "{}" sign on the line 15:

```
print "Athlete: {$row[0]} Year: {$row[3]}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Internal Server error is shown when you don't have the `display_error`s flag set to `on` (php.ini) and you get an error in your PHP script.

The error comes from your sql

```
$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM olympics WHERE EXTRACT(month from "closing_ceremony_date")=theMonth AND EXTRACT(day from "closing_ceremony_date") = theYear");
```

try to write it like this:

```
$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM olympics WHERE EXTRACT(month from closing_ceremony_date) = '$theMonth' AND EXTRACT(day from closing_ceremony_date) = '$theYear'");
```

I'm assuming here that closing_ceremony_date is a column in your data table.

Comment: Hm, thanks. I've changed it to this and am still getting an internal server error.

Comment: Are you able to switch `display_error` to `On` in your php.ini file? That might be helpful for debugging.

Comment: Unfortunately not :/ It's a read only file on the school server and my permissions won't let me write to it. Thank you for the idea though.